# How can we track face in AR foundation (ARKit3) but not show front camera to the device screen?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit

Basically, there is a problem with ARFoundation package in Unity3D.
At first, I generate avatar model from the AvatarSDK. Not really important at this problem. but anyway. It returns skinned mesh renderer with blendshapes.

What I want to do next is to control those blendshapes with my own face through front camera. For this, on my scene I loaded ARSession/ARInputManager, ARSessionOrigin/ARFaceManager.

Then, when by model is generated, I enable ARFaceManager component to track face.
What I see next is front camera image with my virtual model on it.

The problem is I need to track face by front camera, but I do not want to see front camera image on screen.

Can it be solved?

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you need to create a new skybox cubemap material first.

After you've done so, navigate to `AR Session Origin > Main Camera` in your hierarchy and find the `AR Camera Background` component.

Click the `Use Custom Material` checkbox and load your newly created skybox material as the custom material.

This will override the default camera material setting.

Good luck!